# How to print subscripts/superscripts on a CLI?

Tags: c++, command-line, typography, subscript, superscript

I'm writing a piece of code which deals with math variables and indices, and I'd need to print subscripts and superscripts on a CLI, is there a (possibly cross-platform) way to do that? I'm working in vanilla C++.

**Note:** I'd like this to be cross-platform, but since from the first answers this doesn't seem to be possible I'm working under MacOS and Ubuntu Linux (so bash).

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since most CLIs are really only terminals (pretty dumb ones mostly but sometimes with color), the only cross-platform way I've ever done this is by allocating muliple physical lines per virtual line, such as:

```
        2
f(x) = x  + log x
               2
```

It's not ideal but it's probably the best you're going to get without a GUI.

Following you extra information as to what platforms you're mainly interested in:

With Ubuntu at least, gnome-terminal runs in UTF-8 mode by default so the following code shows how to generate the superscripts and subscripts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char *super[] = {"\xe2\x81\xb0", "\xc2\xb9", "\xc2\xb2",
    "\xc2\xb3", "\xe2\x81\xb4", "\xe2\x81\xb5", "\xe2\x81\xb6",
    "\xe2\x81\xb7", "\xe2\x81\xb8", "\xe2\x81\xb9"};
static char *sub[] = {"\xe2\x82\x80", "\xe2\x82\x81", "\xe2\x82\x82",
    "\xe2\x82\x83", "\xe2\x82\x84", "\xe2\x82\x85", "\xe2\x82\x86",
    "\xe2\x82\x87", "\xe2\x82\x88", "\xe2\x82\x89"};

int main(void) {
    int i;
    printf ("f(x) = x%s + log%sx\n",super[2],sub[2]);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf ("x%s x%s ", super[i], sub[i]);
    }
    printf ("y%s%s%s z%s%s\n", super[9], super[9], super[9], sub[7], sub[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

The `super` and `sub` char* arrays are the UTF-8 encodings for the Unicode code points for numeric superscripts and subscripts (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)). The given program will output my formula from above (on one line instead of three), then another test line for all the choices and a y-super-999 and z-sub-75 so you can see what they look like.

MacOS doesn't appear to use gnome-terminal as a terminal program but references [here](http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/40) and [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714) seem to indicate the standard terminal understands UTF-8 (or you could download and install gnome-terminal as a last resort).

Comment: What about a non-cross-platform way?

Comment: That would depend on the platform :-) If you can tell us the platforms you expect to be able to run on, we may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 8):

> I'd need to print subscripts and superscripts on a CLI, is there a cross-platform way to do that?

Only if you have a Unicode-capable terminal, which is far from guaranteed. Unicode defines a limited number of sub- and superscript ‘compatibility characters’, you certainly can't use it on any old letter:

```
₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎ₐₑₒₓ
⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿⁱ
```

Even then you're reliant on there being a glyph for it in the console font, which is also far from guaranteed. Superscript 2 and 3 are likely to exist as they're present in ISO-8859-1; the others may well not work.

Comment: I actually just need numeric subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: And, ok, but how to print them from C++?

Comment: wchar_t/wprintf/std::wstring, I guess.