# Trying to write the delta-O-18 sign in Python

Tags: python, letters

I am new to  python and It seems like a small issue, but I was unable to find the answer for it on the web.
I want to write the delta O 18 sign, the one from the famous isotope ratio expression, but with no luck so far: 
Basically, I need to make the "18" in the following expression to "go" up - plt.ylabel('$\delta18O$')

Thanks in advance for all of you.

Best,
N.

Comment: I think this is really a (La)TeX question, not a Python question.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "superscript". Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8651361/10077

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. If your program needs to render text, is that on a terminal (basically no can do, in the general case), a graphical environment (which one?), a physical device (which one?) or what?

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the answer for it: '$\\delta^{18}O_{SMOW}$. Fred Larson, you were right, all I needed was a superscript.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some help from friends - '$\delta^{18}O_{SMOW}$

N.