# Superscript a symbol in a string passed to reportlab drawString() method

Tags: python, reportlab, superscript

Is there a simple means of superscripting a substring (e.g. a `'%'` symbol) of a string in Python when writing that string to a PDF using `reportlab` via the `drawString()` method?

Let's say for example, printing a string such as `'37%'`, where I want the `'%'` symbol to be a superscripted.

My current workaround I suppose is to instead use two separate calls to the `drawString()` method and specify separate font sizes for each, with coordinates that effectively simulate the superscript notation. Are there any other feasible workarounds that limit this to one call of the `drawString()` method?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651361/how-do-you-print-superscript-in-python

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using the terminal? Terminals don't support superscript. You'd have to use something like `bearlibterminal`.

Comment: I will be printing the string to a PDF using reportlab and passing the string to the drawString() method

Comment: @RickAhlf please edit your question to include that, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you end up doing a lot with math and formulas you may wish to consider using LaTex which can be converted to a pdf.

I don't think what you are asking is doable with the drawString method but reportlab offers another method that allows it.

This article should be of great help to you: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/02/06/reportlab-101-the-textobject/

Adapting directly from the article gives us this code:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def apply_scripting(textobject, text, rise):
    textobject.setFont("Helvetica-Oblique", 8)
    textobject.setRise(rise)
    textobject.textOut(text)
    textobject.setFont("Helvetica-Oblique", 12)
    textobject.setRise(0)

def main():
    canvas_obj = canvas.Canvas("textobj_rising.pdf",
                               pagesize=letter)

    # Create textobject
    textobject = canvas_obj.beginText()
    textobject.setFont("Helvetica-Oblique", 12)

    # Set text location (x, y)
    textobject.setTextOrigin(10, 730)

    textobject.textOut('37')
    apply_scripting(textobject, '%', 4)

    canvas_obj.drawText(textobject)
    canvas_obj.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which creates a pdf like this:

[image: pdf with superscript]

The advantage of this over drawString twice is you don't need to figure out the coordinates for where to place the `%` symbol.

Comment: Awesome solution, worked exactly as I needed it to! Thank you for the helpful linked article as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot` to do this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(title= r'This is an expression:  $37^{\%}$')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this is saved as a string however. Would I be able to pass this to the drawString() method when printing a string to a reportlab generated PDF?