# How to superscript in a print statement in python 3?

Tags: python, math, superscript

I've been trying to append a unit into a calculated value using the print statement in python 3, but I can't seem to find a way to get the unit to print as a superscript.

print ("I max = ", np.amax(intensity363), "J m$^-2$")

I've currently got tex, but I've tried html style with as I do it on a graph axes, and various other options listed in this post

[How do you print superscript in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651361/how-do-you-print-superscript-in-python)

but none work, given the age of this post I'm wondering if its a python 2/3 thing.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why didn't this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8651412

Comment: @user3080953. "assuming your console supports Unicode".

Comment: I assume you are printing to a console? Then it will require your console to support that. Python (3) uses unicode natively. Your console may support unicode, but I doubt it will interpret tex or html, why would you think so?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such a built-in feature. You can use Unicode if you need some fancy symbols, e.g.

```
>>> print("%d⁻²" % 42)
42⁻²
```

You need to look up the different codes if you need something more dynamic than just the "-2".

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you're working with Jupyter you might be interested in this approach, if indeed you're not already using it.

[image: embedded Latex]

This is done in Py2 only because I haven't installed Py3 in Jupyter. I expect it works in essentially the same way.