# Pygame: display exponent in text

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I cant seem to figure out how to write 3^3 without the up pointing arrow. 
as i am making a mainly text-based program it's just going to look ugly.

I have not tried to do much yet. I am mainly making this post for others to find, i will probably find the solution myself, but any help is appreciated.

So my question is: 
can i write something in my string that will enable exponents?
if not, will i have to write my own string interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this can be done with

```
f'string morestring \N{SUPERSCRIPT x}'
```

x here is the letter version of the number.

SUBSCRIPT also works.

answer found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49442772/9777524