# I need to superscript letters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The letter 'st' needs to be superscripted. Got unicodes that scripted number. Any help with strings? Without the use of extra modules.

```py
name = ['Sanjay','sai','clarke','Bellamy']
for i, name in enumerate(name):
    print(f'{i}st place goes to {name}')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you print superscript in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651361/how-do-you-print-superscript-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consoles don't support superscripts natively.

You can leave it like that, or use some special characters to show that (ˢᵗ), but those might not be supported in some fonts or terminals.