# Printing the exponent in scientific numbers with superscript characters

Tags: python

I have a float number stored as scientific notation in a tuple:

```
correlation = (1,1.1884423896339773e-06)
```

I want to reformat that float (`correlation[1]`) into the following format, to be plotted as a string in a plot:

```
1.19 * 10^-6         # '-6' should be in superscript actually here
```

However, I am getting an `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-4: truncated \uXXXX escape`

```
lsF = str(correlation[1])
ePos = lsF.find("e")
if (ePos):
    base = float(lsF[:ePos])
    exponent = int(lsF[ePos+1:])
else:
    base = float(lsF)
    exponent = 0
print(round(base, 2), " * 10", eval(r'"\u00b' + str(exponent) + '"'), sep="")
```

When my `exponent` is positive, this works well.

Comment: I didn't understand which part of this code is supposed to make superscript.

Comment: The last one (`print`), the code above is to extract the exponent and the base (I'm happy for improvements here too!)

Comment: What do you mean by "it works well"? If I use `base = 3.4; exponent = 5`, it prints `3.4 * 10µ`, but nothing is in superscript.

Comment: oh sh*t, I only tried ` exponent = 2 `, and that did work :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you print superscript in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651361/how-do-you-print-superscript-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the superscript numbers is that the UTF-8 codes are not contiguous, you need a translation table.

Here is one way to do it with the help of f-strings:

```
def scientific_superscript(num, digits=2):
    base, exponent = f'{num:.{digits}e}'.split('e')
    d = dict(zip('-+0123456789','⁻⁺⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'))
    return f'{base}⋅10{"".join(d.get(x, x) for x in  exponent)}'

scientific_superscript(1.1884423896339773e-06)
# '1.19⋅10⁻⁰⁶'

scientific_superscript(3.141e123)
# '3.14⋅10⁺¹²³'
```

###### blacklisting characters:

example for 0 and +

```
def scientific_superscript(num, digits=2):
    base, exponent = f'{num:.{digits}e}'.split('e')
    d = dict(zip('-+0123456789','⁻⁺⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'))
    return f'{base}⋅10{"".join(d.get(x, x) for x in exponent.lstrip("0+"))}'

scientific_superscript(3.141e3)
# '3.14⋅10³'

scientific_superscript(1e103)
# '1.00⋅10¹⁰³'
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this! How would I get rid of the `0` in `-06`, because you transform the exponent to string, right?

Comment: @rororo check the update ;) I transform the initial number to string in the beginning to ensure having an exponent.

Comment: yes! the `+` would have been my second question, for someone with slight OCD :)

Comment: The blacklist approach would not work for something like `e=103`, you can use `lstrip()` on `exponent` instead

Comment: @Jay why not? See update. I realized however I had forgotten the `⋅10` in the display ;)

Comment: @Jay nevermind I understand you, fixing it ;)

Comment: @mozway, the `*10` was correct :)